# Thread safe access to HttpRequest.InputStream in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I develop a .NET library that helps with logging and could be used in ASP.NET applications. In my code I have to read and analyse body of the Http request.

Currently I do it like that:

```
        var stream = HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(
            stream,
            encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
            detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true,
            bufferSize: 1024,
            leaveOpen: true))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }

        // Another thread reads HttpContext.Request.InputStream here ...

        stream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

My concern is:

I change position of the stream that could be accessed by application code outside of my library. Other thread could access stream before I restore it (seek to origin).

What if other thread (e.g. Task created by code that handles request) reads the same stream in the same time?

Can application that uses my library be impacted?

If yes - how to avoid it?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not implementing your library as a [normal middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) then you don't need to worry about parallel streams processing the data.

Comment: Yes. My library is an "extension" for log4net (contains custom repository selector) and attached to application declaratively via app.config (without any changes in code). But middleware will require a reference to my assembly and explicit usage in code. Also middleware is for ASP.NET Core / ASP.NET 5. What about older versions?

Comment: Assuming you're targeting ASP.NET (and not ASP.NET Core), that's what the synchronization context is here for. Since the HttpContext (and everything under it) isn't thread-safe, you're supposed to access it only from the thread of the synchronization context. Of course you can't guarantee that the client app is actually doing that, but then it's not your fault anymore

Comment: Also, note that accessing `InputStream` will fail if the client application uses the HttpRequest without buffering (usually for performance reasons). You should check the ReadEntityBodyMode property first, and degrade gracefully is it's set to Bufferless: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.readentitybodymode?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpRequest_ReadEntityBodyMode

Comment: If I understand correctly I should use SynchronizationContext.Current.Send(...) to execute my code in the same thread that handles request. 
Please see demo [link](https://pastebin.com/Uezceusp). It seems like SynchronizationContext.Current is null for Tasks (thread pool threads).
My code is executed by log4net, somewhere inside ILog.Info(...).
So if someone calls logging in task I won't be able to access SynchronizationContext.Current of the main thread.
Does it mean that users always have to use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext for their tasks?